# Excel Multiply one set of values with given matrix and sum results

Tags: excel

I need to redistribute values for Old entries by using new distribution in a given table.

Example:
[image: OLD Elements with values]

Need to redistribute using given % in this table:

[image: NEW Distribution of values]

So New Value of Element 1 = 99% * old1 + 7% * old2 + 3% * old3 + 26% * old5

This is not whole table, it is pretty large. There must be a simpler way than adding things up manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MMULT()` worksheet function for that.

Example:

```
               A      B       C       D        E        F
1         Amount                              
2            100
3            200
4            500
5            400
6                                  
7    Percentages      1       2       3       4      
8                    99       7       3      26      =MMULT(B8:E8;A$2:A$5)/100
9                     1      93      34       0      =MMULT(B9:E9;A$2:A$5)/100
10                    0       0      63      74      =MMULT(B10:E10;A$2:A$5)/100
```

For your information: I've entered the first formula in F8, and dragged and dropped until F10.

Comment: This however solves only for "1". If I am going to make same for all items, its going to be same as I am doing this manually.

Comment: I'll make you another example and edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, `MMULT()` seems to be better :-)